# Tensorflow/keras when passing tuple of tensors to multiple loss functions, only one tensor in tuple is being passed using .fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

The shape of the training data is:

```
pred: [
         ([batch], 52, 52, 3, 6),
         ([batch], 26, 26, 3, 6),
         ([batch], 13, 13, 3, 6),
    ]
true: [
        [
         ([batch], 52, 52, 3, 6),
         ([batch], 128, 4),
        ],
        [
         ([batch], 26, 26, 3, 6),
         ([batch], 128, 4),
        ],
        [
         ([batch], 13, 13, 3, 6),
         ([batch], 128, 4),
        ]
    ]
```

I have 3 outputs, and have specified a loss function for each by passing a list of losses to model.compile. The problem is when training, the loss function only recieves one of the two values that it is meant to. When I call it manually it works fine.

E.g.:
With

```
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(), 
    loss = losses
)
```

This produces the correct behaviour

```
losses[0](y[0], model(x)[0])
```

And the output of this:

```
def loss(target, output):
    print(output.shape)
    print(target[0].shape)
    print(target[1].shape)
```

is:

```
(1, 52, 52, 18)
(1, 52, 52, 3, 6)
(1, 128, 4)
```

But when calling the loss using:

```
model.fit(x,y,batch_size=1)
```

I get these dimensions:

```
(1, 52, 52, 18)
(52, 52, 3, 6)
```

And then this error:

```
ValueError: slice index 1 of dimension 0 out of bounds
```

Suggesting that only one of the tensors in the tuple is being passed at a time when called through .fit

I would really like to avoid a custom training loop as to take advantage of features such as callbacks etc. so is there any way to pass both the tensors to the loss function in a tuple at once?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? In its state, your code is hard to read (function changing name (`loss` vs `losses`), undefined variable (`x`,`y`), etc.).

Answer (score 2):

This reproduces the issue:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.full((100,1), 1.0))
y0 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.full((100,1), 2.0))
y1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.full((100,1), 3.0))
y = tf.data.Dataset.zip((y0, y1))

train_data = tf.data.Dataset.zip((x, y)) 

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,))
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(inputs)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

def myloss(y_true, y_pred):
    y0 = y_true[0]
    y1 = y_true[1]
    return tf.reduce_mean((y0 - y_pred)**2 + 0.5*(y1 - y_pred)**2)

model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=myloss)
model.fit(train_data, epochs=1)
```

Here the target y is a tuple, but when passing it to the loss function model.fit only includes the first element of the tuple.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: The problem lies in the implementation of train_step only. So this can be worked around by writing a custom train_step method. The Keras doc has examples of bare bone working versions of that method.